# Can a written notice of reason for withholding a holding deposit be given electronically?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules

Bob has gone on a viewing for a property and put down a holding deposit. Most of the communication about the property was with an agent via WhatsApp. However at a certain point he was asked to email the director of the company with this or that. They required certain documents that he had at the time misplaced and so a couple of weeks later he took advice and found that he was entitled to a refund of the holding deposit as he had not been given a written notice of any reason for withholding it. He requested the deposit back from them by sending a text message to the director of the company. The director simply replied “sorry but the deposit is not refundable.”

Bob was preparing to claim it back at the tribunal when at a certain point he noticed that there was in fact an emailed evocation of the reason for withholding the HD that was within the 7 day limit but it had been caught by his spam filter and most of his communication with the company has been via mobile communications anyway so he had not been expecting any emails from them. The email had apparently been sent in reply to a previous mobile text message inquiry he had made as to having his deposit refunded but no indication was made by text of the email that was being sent.

Simply speaking Bob had never consented or made any prior agreement to receive the explanation that is required to be in writing by email and was indeed not expecting it.

Legally speaking was Bob then “served” this “written” letter of explanation required under the tenant fees act?

Comment: How could they inform you via an email address unless you gave it to them? And having done that it is your responsibility to check your email, and "whitelist" such an important correspondant. Email is "written notice". *Most of the communication about the property was with an agent via WhatsApp* — **electronic**.

Answer (score 3):

### It’s too hard to call

The UK, unlike many jurisdictions, does not have a single Act that sets out the rules for electronic communications. The *Electronic Communications Act* allows the Minister to set rules for each of the Acts within their purview but AFAIK, the power has not been used for the *Tenant Fees Act*.

The only info I have been able to find is a comment on [this](https://blog.openrent.co.uk/whatsapp-email-or-letters-whats-best-for-landlord-tenant-communication/) post:

> Landlords should be aware that there is no general provision for serving legal notices or prescribed documents electronically. A tenant would have to give prior written consent, (with a wet signature) to be served these things by email, (including s21/s8 notices, EPC, Gas Safety, How to Rent, EiCR etc). As far as I am aware there is no provision for serving these documents by whatsapp or similar. With legally required documents, the issue is about whether they have been served, not whether the tenant has a copy.

Bob has a copy, but has bee been *served* a copy? The situation is sufficiently murky that this is unclear.  When Bob takes this to the tribunal, please let us know the outcome.